# Are there any pins that need to be wired in certain ways for the ESP8266 to work?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, wifi

So I'm making a PCB for a project so I don't need to use a node mcu and only need the esp8266 but I not exactly sure if there are any pins that should be wired obligatorily for it to work.

Here is my schematic. (It's just an external button  wired to the ESP8266)

[image]

Will this work like this or are any pins that should be connected so it powers up and its programmable?

Comment: hardware design guidelines: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong and that is unfortunate because lots of people may follow it. So, I have decided to elaborate a right answer to help others in case they navigate through the answers.

Unfortunately, the Hardware Guidelines suggested by some people in the comments will not be very helpful as it mainly talks about the ESP8266EX IC. Which may be confusing and overwhelming, as a good chunk of circuitry presented in the guide already exists in the ESP8266-12F module. Under the metal shield and out of reach.

So, in order to bring the the ESP8266-12F to a normal operation, you need to make sure some pins are in the correct state:

GPIO0 - PULL UP

GPIO15 - PULL DOWN

CHIP_EN - PULL UP

The resistors may vary. But anything from 5k to 12k will do it. Dont forget that the device is a 3v3 and do not tolerate 5V. Before you apply power, make sure you are under this constraint

It is also good practice to hold RST pin up to avoid unexpected resets. But, it is not a requirement for operation it is just a safety measure. Some designs use a 100nF Capacitor to GND instead of a pull up resistor. Which would also keep RST pin stable.

Here is an example schematic

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pin 3 EN needs to be pulled to VCC for the module to boot as far as I know, other than that I think it's good.
[image]
[https://components101.com/wireless/esp12e-pinout-datasheet#:~:text=ESP%2D12E%20is%20a%20miniature,connection%20for%20microcontroller%20or%20processor.&text=It%20features%20ability%20to%20embed,function%20as%20a%20standalone%20application](https://components101.com/wireless/esp12e-pinout-datasheet#:%7E:text=ESP%2D12E%20is%20a%20miniature,connection%20for%20microcontroller%20or%20processor.&text=It%20features%20ability%20to%20embed,function%20as%20a%20standalone%20application).

Comment: this answers is wrong. see the hardware design guidelines : https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf

Comment: @Juraj so what pins should I connect so it works properly?

Comment: @DeadSec, there is a schematics in the pdf

Comment: @Juraj I'm not sure the link you sent is relevant to the module we were discussing, unless I'm missing something? what page are you referring too in the. pfd?

Comment: @DeadSec, you asked about plain esp8266. now I see you have esp-12f label in the schematics

Comment: @Juraj so do you know what pins should I use?

Comment: @DeadSec, google found this for "esp-12 wiring": https://easyeda.com/gerdmuller.de/ESP8266_12F_Minimal_Wiring-USM4lfxP7 it looks right